# IntelliJ IDEA warning highlighting on not using an abstract method?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

[image: http://puu.sh/6U1Yk.jpg]

I just switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA, and I imported all of my old projects, but I'm getting insane warnings.

For example, when looking at the image pasted above, it gives warnings on abstract methods not being used, classes not being used, even imports that aren't being used when they clearly are.

Finally, what is the hotkey for importing? Like in Eclipse it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

Any additional tips if all is resolved that I should know that is different from IntelliJ and Eclipse?

Comment: I think that that is a warning not an error.

Comment: Well, I don't know about your first question but the hotkey for importing seems to be Crtl + Alt + O. Found it here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf